# Is there a performance downside of using Groovy with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, groovy

Spring framework supports the use of dynamic languages like Groovy.

Since Groovy can be now static compiled, a groovy class is supposed to have similar performance compared with a Java class as far as I know.

So for example if I write my spring beans in Groovy by importing the class files or by using the lang:groovy element like:

```
<lang:groovy id="myBean" script-source="classpath:mypackage/MyClass.groovy" />
```

or an inline definition like:

```
<lang:groovy id="myBean">
    <lang:inline-script>
        package mypackage

        class MyClass {
            String helloWorld() { "Hello World" }
        }
    </lang:inline-script>
</lang:groovy>
```

My question is if this affects the performance of the application in comparison with using only java classes, also I wonder if there will be issues when working with beans with different scopes than singleton like prototype, session, request.

Has anyone experience on developing Spring apps with this approach? I mean real world professional projects.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." - [Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: You shouldn't be worrying about the speed you can create spring beans

Comment: BTW: the answers to this are _"of course there is"_, and _"it probably won't affect you"_

Comment: The point of your question is unclear: are you asking whether it's slower to use uncompiled Groovy, use Groovy at all, or use one of those two styles of bean definition?

Comment: BTW the difference in performance between compiled and uncompiled Groovy is  probably smaller than the difference between compiled Groovy and compiled Java. This is because Groovy stays just as much a dynamic language as it was before compiling.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik not necessarily, and it also depends if you use `CompileStatic` annotation surely?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Marko actually the point of the question is to know if it is worth going for the use of groovy for creating beans in Eclipse enterprise apps from a performance perspective. If you think that the different styles of bean definition will mean different performance, then can you please answer the question and elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, if you use `CompileStatic`, you change the semantics to non-dynamic. But people tend to use Groovy *because* it is a dynamic language---otherwise they have Java.

Comment: That is what I always say to the managers in the companies I have worked for @Elliot Frish :) but there is always people worrying about performance and speed at any time

Comment: @raspacorp "Eclipse enterprise apps"? Not sure what that means. But as far as I can see, your question has nothing to do with Spring---you're asking whether it pays to make your application in Groovy.

Comment: @tim_yates I agree but if you come to the managers/architects and explain them that the use of Groovy will contribute to improve developers productivity, they always ask you back about the performance overhead. That is the intention of the question they are worried about that because they are worried about money and infrastructure in large projects

Comment: @raspacorp Why would  Groovy contribute to productivity? I am not convinced it will, especially on massive projects, where type safety is actually a benefit.

Comment: @raspacorp And there are (seemingly sane) people who program in assembler...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik sorry by mistake I said Eclipse but was trying to say Spring enterprise apps. My idea is to use both Java and Groovy, for example the beans that may have more complex logic and working with Collections and those things that are verbose can benefit of the use of Groovy, at the same time other ones that do heavy use of inheritance and interfaces can be done in Java

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you can use  CompileStatic to get type safety, but still use the brevity of groovy without the boilerplate and utilising ast transforms for example

Comment: If I was the manager, I'd be quite skeptical about letting Groovy in, or any second language. Java is not without reason the golden standard of enterprise apps: it's robust, performant, reliable, well documented, has a rich market of developers, etc. With Groovy I'm allowing a big unknown into my project. BTW I'm a great fan and practitioner of Clojure, and for all I said above, you can substitute Clojure for Groovy.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I think Groovy really improves productivity as other languages like Ruby do, they are more expressive and have lot of shortcuts for example working with collections and many others. I worked 1 year in the past with application integration apps using Grails and we were able to deliver really fast and that was not only because of Grails but because of Groovy language

Comment: @raspacorp They increase productivity as in banging out features, yes. But they also increase bugginess and make bugs harder to track down. Dynamic languages demand greater discipline and in the hands of so-so developers (which is the reality on almost all larger projects) they are a menace.

Comment: Also note that performance in enterprise apps mainly suffers not from the inadequacies of language, but from monstrosities committed by developers. Here, too, dynamic languages are an accomplice by allowing one to write what looks like simple and elegant code, but is in fact brain-dead---something like `sql("select * from trade").filter(t -> t.price > minPrice)`.

Comment: It seems that Spring 4 has full out of the box support for Groovy language. Maybe performance issues won't be a problem anymore: http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/12/announcing-spring-framework-4-0-ga-release

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java tends to do some amazing optimizations--these days I'm convinced that it's just so that frameworks that do cause performance hits don't noticably change the performance of most apps.

Spring fits this.  If you look at a stack dump when you've been using Spring heavily you will see around 10 frames injected between method calls every so often.  Whenever spring has to intercept your code it does a lot of work!  Thing is, Java is so fast that even though it might slow your method call down by a factor of 100x, who cares?  It's still 1000x faster than you need it to be.

The other thing--statically compiled groovy can be quite quick, but if you really care, pay attention because if you fall into the groovy libraries you may end up spending quite a bit longer than you'd think.

Overall though the biggest thing to remember is what the first commenter said about the root of all evil.

Paying attention to performance up front almost never makes sense.  Even if you KNOW you will have performance issues, code it as readably as you can then profile it and go back and convert places that turned out to be too slow.

Comment: Great answer. Groovy libraries is what most people overlook when they discuss raw Java vs. static Groovy performance.